# How to replace one table(HTML) with other dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The other table is exactly same except some data changes.All i want is to change this tables with other table dynamically on a button click.

```
<TABLE BORDER="5" WIDTH="50%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>TABLE TITLE</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>Column A</TH>
      <TH>Column B</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD>Data 1</TD>
      <TD>Data 2</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
<button href="#">next table
</button>
```

Comment: What other table? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the other table is exactly same. I haven't tried anything as i am a beginner to this.

Comment: I would suggest looking for tutorials on HTML replacement.

Comment: Why? it can't be done using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily implement this with some JavaScript.

```js
visible = 1; //var that keeps track of which table is visible (1 or 2)
function change_table() {
  t1 = document.getElementById("TABLE1");
  t2 = document.getElementById("TABLE2");
  if(visible == 1) {
    visible = 2;
    t1.style.display = 'none';
    t2.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    visible = 1;
    t1.style.display = 'block';
    t2.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<TABLE ID='TABLE1' BORDER="5" WIDTH="50%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3" STYLE="display: block;">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>TABLE TITLE</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>Column A</TH>
      <TH>Column B</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD>Data 1</TD>
      <TD>Data 2</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
  <TABLE ID='TABLE2' BORDER="5" WIDTH="50%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3" STYLE="display: none;">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>TABLE TITLE</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>Column C</TH>
      <TH>Column D</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD>Data 3</TD>
      <TD>Data 4</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
<button onclick="change_table()">next table
</button>
```

Comment: it shows an error that change_table is defined but never used

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is the browser or IDE giving the error? Does it work?

Comment: no not browser my compiler (dreamweaver) is

Comment: You probably forgot to edit the button with the new `onclick="change_table()"`

Comment: No buddy i put this exactly like you've written

Comment: If you run it in a browser, does it work?

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: @aman It does work, you've probably got a "linter" which is stopping it from running.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide/show the table you want visible/hidden.

There are many ways to do this, a good pratice is to just add/remove class which adds for example: `display: block;` or `display: none;`

Comment: want to make it act according to button

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is your friend. Keeping it simple, for example:

```
document.getElementById('tableCell').innerHTML = 'New Content';
```

where for example you have some ID's or classes in your table (see cell with "Data 1" text):

```
<TABLE BORDER="5" WIDTH="50%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>TABLE TITLE</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>Column A</TH>
      <TH>Column B</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD id="tableCell">Data 1</TD>
      <TD>Data 2</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
<button href="#">next table
</button>
```

EDITED:
to append a function to your button you can do this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

and you will have to declare your function where all the real fun will be:

```
function myFunction(){
/* change table cell values here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").on('click', function(){
    $("#table1").empty();
    $('#table1').append('<TR><TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>TABLE TITLE</H3></TH></TR>');
    $('#table1').append('<TR><TH>Column A</TH><TH>Column B</TH></TR>');
    var max = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    for(var i=0;i < max;i++){
      $('#table1').append('<TR ALIGN="CENTER"><TD>Data ' + i + '</TD><TD>Data ' + i + '</TD></TR>');
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE id="table1" BORDER="5" WIDTH="50%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>TABLE TITLE</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>Column A</TH>
      <TH>Column B</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD>Data 1</TD>
      <TD>Data 2</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
<button href="#">next table
</button>
```

Comment: i have two tables i want to show them according to click